# Pretty print Python Lists

Tags: python, list, formatting

I have written a CLI Utility in python and I have a list with 1:M list-items of paths like:
[image: imgggg]

I want to display the list in a more `readable manner` like:

```
[
(1, '/path/here'), ('path/here/again'), 
(2, 'a/different/path/here'), ('another/path/here')
]
```

or in a `table-like` format (e.g.):

```
1    /path/here                path/here/again
2    a/different/path/here     another/path/here
```

Note, this list could have say like 20 or more list-items.

Thanks!

Comment: Use `rjust(number_of_spaces)`

Comment: The output in the screenshot seems to have a different data structure than the code you typed in.

Comment: Did you take a look at https://docs.python.org/2/library/pprint.html ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start:

```
>>> mylist = [
... (1, '/path/here', 'path/here/again'),
... (2, 'a/different/path/here', 'another/path/here')
... ]
```

Play with `join()`, `map()`, and `str()`, along with Python 3's nice `print()` function:

```
>>> print(*('\t'.join(map(str, item)) for item in mylist), sep='\n')
1       /path/here      path/here/again
2       a/different/path/here   another/path/here
```

Or you could try string formatting instead of `join()` and `map()`:

```
>>> print(*(str(col) + '\t' + (len(item)*'{}').format(*(i.ljust(25) for i in item)) for col,*item in mylist), sep='\n')
1       /path/here               path/here/again
2       a/different/path/here    another/path/here
```

You could also look into the [`pprint`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/pprint.html) module.

Comment: What about Python 2 version?..I'm just saying because the OP didn't mention the version he is using..

Comment: That part's trivial: you just `'\n'.join()` that generator, or do `for line in the_generator: print line`.